PowerAutomate, need to loop and extract valueString
Very new to using Json and PoweAutomate, need to get the ValueString out for the following code on each object (i.e. Amount / Description).  There could be multiple objects as this is from the Azure Document Processing of a scanned invoice. Feel like there is something simple to display the "valueNumber" below. UPDATE: sorry pasted a different code, have two of them that switch the "valueNumber" and "valueString"

    "Items": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "valueArray": [
                            {
                                "type": "object",
                                "valueObject": {
                                    "Amount": {
                                        "type": "number",
                                        "valueNumber": 23.98,
                                        "text": "23.98",
                                        "boundingBox": [
                                            7.1214,
                                            3.565,
                                            7.4251,
                                            3.565,
                                            7.4251,
                                            3.6563,
                                            7.1214,
                                            3.6563
                                        ],
                                        "page": 1,
                                        "confidence": 0.935
                                    },




which value do you want to extract?

there is no property called valueString in your data. Please edit your question and post your desired result and what you have tried.

Updated, sorry for the confusion need valueNumber on this one, but there is more code below it with valueString

you'll need a 'Parse JSON' action, where you can put your JSON payload.
After it, a 'Compose' action can extract the desired values. Based on your code sample (it needed some tweaks with closing parentheses), the 'valueNumber' parameter (which should be 23.98) can get via this expression:
body('Parse_JSON')?['Items']['valueArray'][0]['ValueObject']['Amount']['valueNumber']

